# Warning: "Attempted Frozen Title Change"

Tags: facebook-opengraph

Our website (www.seeing.org) has recently changed its title and we have also decided to increase its Facebook integration, including making use of the following Object Property `og:title`:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Bates Method International - the Bates Method of Vision Education" />
```

However on debugging the page I'm issued with the following warning:

> "Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed ": Attempted Frozen Title
>   Change
>
> "It appears that you are trying to change the property og:title from
>   Bates Method - Bates Association for Vision Education to Bates Method
>   International - the Bates Method of Vision Education. If so, you are
>   not allowed to for this object because too many actions have been
>   published against it."

It appears that the only way I could 'fix' this problem is to change the page title back to what Facebook thinks it should be. However, this is not the title of the website so that is a completely unsatisfactory - and untruthful - solution.

I've checked over a number of similar posts about this issue, but no one has suggested a way of applying to have it fixed properly: in my case that means getting the `og:title` to perform accurately in representing the website and the true name of its organization.

Comment: try to contact with facebook.